# Why am I getting these Django security warnings, but not other developers on the team

Tags: python, django

I am currently getting the following Django security warnings when running makemigrations:

```
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (security.W004) You have not set a value for the SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS setting. If your entire site is served only over SSL, you may want to consider setting a value and enabling HTTP Strict Transport Security. Be sure to read the documentation first; enabling HSTS carelessly can cause serious, irreversible problems.
?: (security.W006) Your SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF setting is not set to True, so your pages will not be served with an 'x-content-type-options: nosniff' header. You should consider enabling this header to prevent the browser from identifying content types incorrectly.) SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE is not set to True. Using a secure-only session cookie makes it more difficult for network traffic sniffers to hijack user sessions.(security.W019) You have 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware' in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, but X_FRAME_OPTIONS is not set to 'DENY'. The default is 'SAMEORIGIN', but unless there is a good reason for your site to serve other parts of itself in a frame, you should change it to 'DENY'.
```

followed by a set of other warnings.  I plan on addressing these warnings, but I don't understand why everyone else on my team does not get these warnings.  I am using a Python virtualenv.  Does anyone have any ideas why I am the only one getting these warnings?

I've also verified I don't get these warnings using another computer, it is only my development machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like django version upgraded but not your middlewares. Make sure securitymiddleware is between them.

More info
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/middleware/

Answer (score 5):

The first warning is about the HSTS header which prevents browsers from accessing the data in HTTP. It is typically set to 1 year i.e 31536000 seconds. But under testing conditions you might prefer using a lower value like 60 sec or 3600 sec.

`SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000`

The second warning is to prevent sniffing attacks. This can be prevented by adding the following line in your settings.py

`SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True`

Documentations :

1. On HSTS Settings ([here)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secure-hsts-seconds)
2. [On NOSNIFF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF)
3. [Other Security Middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secure-browser-xss-filter)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably the version of Django you're using. [Version 1.8 and later use HSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/middleware/#http-strict-transport-security).